# chromedriver not found error on heroku app

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, heroku, selenium-chromedriver

I want to use selenium on my heroku app. So I added following buildpacks. 
[image: Screenshot of buildpacks in my heroku app]

Following is the python code which uses the selenium, chrome and chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver

# from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

import os

import pickle

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions

chrome_bin = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM', None)
opts = ChromeOptions()
opts.binary_location = chrome_bin
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver", 
chrome_options=opts)
```

I am getting following error
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'chromedriver': 'chromedriver'

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering for anyone who has same problem. So the problem was when I was adding buildpacks then it was asking me to run "git push heroku master" to use buildpack in app but that was not working. You need to make change in code and the you should push code on git so that it app runs again it rebuild itself.